# Vue.js - Why my child component cannot access store getter as property?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, getter

I defined a getter in my store, and i try to access it within my child components, but i only can access it as a method...

I read in the doc we could access it as a property, but when im doing so, it returns me the signature of the getter function, here is my code :
const store = {
    state: {
        storage
    },
    getters: {
        username: (state, getters) => {
            return 'tmp';
        }
    }
}

My child component :

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            username: this.initialUsername
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapMutations([
            'login'
        ]),
        onLogin(e) {
            this.login(this.username);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            initialUsername: 'username'
        })
    },
    created() {
        console.log(this.username)
    }
}
```

What i get in the console :

```
ƒ username(state, getters) {
      return 'tmp';
}
```

Any idea why ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Have you tried removing the `getter` parameter from the getters?

What happens if you set the getters like:

getters: { username: state => { return 'tmp'; } }

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i figured out why it didn't work lol, i just didn't instantiate a vuex store, but just a normal object containing my state and getters... :

```
export default {
    state: {
        storage
    },
    getters: {
        username: (state, getters) => {
            return state.storage.username;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        [LOGIN]: (state, username) => {
            state.storage.username = username;
        },
        [LOGOUT]: state => {
            state.storage.logout();
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry buddies, that was the first time I used vuex '-'